# How to set the visibility rule for pane to not show up when any user is logged in?

Tags: panels

I have created three panes (as shown below) using **Mini Panel module**. as named below,

`Login/Register  |   Username  |  Logout`

This I want to keep at the top left of website. Now, how each pane is created

1. `Login/Register`: Created menu and added link named `Login/Register` and have given the path `/user`. So, it leads to login page.
2. `Username`: This I created using the `Views`, a block created of users and filter was given that the user is `logged in`. hence it will automatically show up only when the user is logged in.
3. `Logout`: This I created using menu, with name `Logout` and path `user/logout`, hence when it gets clicked the user gets logout and this pane disappears automatically.
4. When users are logged-in, only the *Username and Logout* pane should appear; hence, users can see their profile by clicking on their name, or they can log out. When users log out, this pane disappears.
5. When user are not logged-in, only the *Login/Register* pane should appear.

So, the *Username and Logout* pane works perfectly fine.

What SELECTION rule shall I give to the *Login/Register* pane, so it gets visible only to anonymous users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While adding a Visibility rule to the pane, select **User:Role** and then select **"anonymous"**. This way the pane will be shown only to anonymous (not logged in) users.

Comment: omg, how this simple thing did not clicked in my mind, even I was familiar with this logic...:) Sometime we start thinking too much and just over look very simple way of doing that. Anyway, Very thanks. Just I checked it is working.